# Using C++ macros to wrap SQLITE error checking and reporting

Tags: c++, c, sqlite

For each of the `sqlite3.*` API, there can be an error code which should be checked. If the code corresponds to an error the related error message can be retrieved via `sqlite3_errmsg(db)`. I am using C++ macros to wrap the logic to perform the call and print the error to stdout if there is any error.

However the following implementation is printing the following error message when  `SQL_CALL_AND_CHECK(db, std::bind(sqlite3_step, sql_stmt))` is called: "no more rows available".

If I perform the SQLITE call without the macro by calling the function directly it just works fine. Could you please help me debug my macro and suggest a cleaner way to wrap error handling in C++?

```
#define SQL_CALL_AND_CHECK(db, fn)                                                        \
  if (fn())                                                                               \
  {                                                                                       \
    std::cout << __FILE__ << "@" << __LINE__ << " : " << sqlite3_errmsg(db) << std::endl; \
  }

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  sqlite3 *db;
  SQL_CALL_AND_CHECK(db, std::bind(sqlite3_open, "new.db", &db));
  sqlite3_stmt *sql_stmt;
  std::string command = "create table if not exists parking ("
                        "parking_id varchar(20) primary key,"
                        "occupied_status binary,"
                        "vehicle_type varchar(20),"
                        "occupied_at time);";
  SQL_CALL_AND_CHECK(db, std::bind(sqlite3_prepare_v2, db, command.c_str(), -1, &sql_stmt, nullptr));
  SQL_CALL_AND_CHECK(db, std::bind(sqlite3_step, sql_stmt));
  SQL_CALL_AND_CHECK(db, std::bind(sqlite3_finalize, sql_stmt));
  SQL_CALL_AND_CHECK(db, std::bind(sqlite3_close, db));
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you treating the `SQLITE_DONE` response as an error? It's not.

Comment: Thanks Shawn. I am a newbie in SQL. I see that there are other non-error result codes: SQLITE_OK, SQLITE_ROW, and SQLITE_DONE. I have made the changes.